# Whether PHP writes file

Tags: php

i tried to search, but still dont know the solution at all, for my next PHP code.

```
<?php
    $city="Budapest"; // Your city
    $country="hu"; // Two digit country code
    $url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$city.",".$country."&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0&units=metric";
    $json=file_get_contents($url);
    $data=json_decode($json,true);
    $file = '/home/cs2d/sys/lua/weather.dat';
    $current = file_get_contents($file);
    $current .= $data['weather'][0]['main']."\n".$data['main']['temp']."\n";
    // Write the contents back to the file
    file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

As you can see it's a simple code, which write values into the weather.dat file.
But how to possible to do that its just refresh lines instead of add new one.

Any idea?

Comment: Is there any error in this script ?

Comment: nope, nothing

Mist
5
Clouds
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5

Its just add news lines instead of replace the first two lines.

Comment: `file_put_contents($file, $current, FILE_APPEND);` possibly?

Comment: You should add What you is your expecting output :) .. that would help us to resolve this question

Comment: @RamRaider Mist
5
Mist
5
Mist
5
 nope. :(

Comment: Mist 5 is the output :)

Comment: You keep adding to the `$current` line, don't do that.

Comment: 5 is the temperature of Hungary, Budapest and Mist is the weaher.

Comment: @JayBlanchard deleted $current but still adds the new lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works :

```
$city="Budapest"; // Your city
$country="hu"; // Two digit country code
$url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=".$city.",".$country."&appid=2de143494c0b295cca9337e1e96b00e0&units=metric";
$json=file_get_contents($url);
$data=json_decode($json,true);
$file = 'weather.dat';

$current = file_get_contents($file);
$contents = file_get_contents($file);
echo $current;
$contents = str_replace($current, ' ', $contents);
echo $contents;

file_put_contents($file,$contents);
$current = file_get_contents($file);
$current .= $data['weather'][0]['main']."\n".$data['main']['temp']."\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
```

Comment: [It's not hard to earn enough rep to make comments.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Comment: Didn't mean to just earn rep. I thought it was a good solution to his question.